# an error while appending data to CellTable second an consequent times in GWT/GWT Platform

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform, gwt-celltable

I'm using  [popup panel](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStarted#Dialog_box_and_popup_panels) of gwt platform and the popup contains two panels on the top panel i have some textboxes and a search button.

and in the second panel contails a cell table which automatically loads some data from db as soon as popup pops out. and from the top panel also i should be able to search for specific  data and update the cell table. i'm using the following code to update the CellTable

```
public void update(List<UserData> data){
        dataProvider.getList().clear();
        List<UserData> dataList=dataProvider.getList();
        for (UserData rtaData : data) {
            dataList.add(rtaData);
        }
        dataProvider.addDataDisplay(cellTable);     
    }
```

my code is working fine but when i see the gwt development mode window in eclipse i can see the following error when ever i click on search button.

```
14:46:25.796 [ERROR] [gwtemotor] Uncaught exception escaped

    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified display has already been added to this adapter.
        at com.google.gwt.view.client.AbstractDataProvider.addDataDisplay(AbstractDataProvider.java:83)
        at com.bagi.emotor.client.ui.presenter.RTOLocationView.update(RTOLocationView.java:230)
        at com.bagi.emotor.client.ui.presenter.RTOLocationPresenter$2.onSuccess(RTOLocationPresenter.java:85)
        at com.bagi.emotor.client.ui.presenter.RTOLocationPresenter$2.onSuccess(RTOLocationPresenter.java:1)
        at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.client.DefaultDispatchAsync.onExecuteSuccess(DefaultDispatchAsync.java:229)
        at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.client.DefaultDispatchAsync$2.onSuccess(DefaultDispatchAsync.java:137)
        at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.client.DefaultDispatchAsync$2.onSuccess(DefaultDispatchAsync.java:1)
        at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:232)
        at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
        at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:395)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
        at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
        at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

even though i'm app is working i need to understand why this error is coming,

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are invoking `dataProvider.addDataDisplay(cellTable);`  on every invocation of the `update(List<UserData> data)`  . addDataDisplay needs to be invoked only once per view.

If You have multiple views, the mvp way is

```
View 1 -> cellTable
View 2 -> cellTree
Presenter -> dataProvider

dataProvider.addDataDisplay(cellTable) 
dataProvider.addDataDisplay(cellTree)
```

### Solution

Move `dataProvider.addDataDisplay` into your constructor or lazy initialize it in `update(List<UserData> data);`

```
boolean initialized = false;

public void update(List<UserData> data){
        dataProvider.getList().clear();
        if(!initialized) {
          dataProvider.addDataDisplay(cellTable);
          initialized = true;
        } 
        List<UserData> dataList=dataProvider.getList();
        for (UserData rtaData : data) {
            dataList.add(rtaData);
        }

    }
```

Comment: please make `dataProvider.getList().clear();` as first line of the method.

Comment: Any particular reason you are adding one item at a time instead of dataProvider.setList( data ) .

Comment: Noo, i didn't check there is a setList method in LDP, following is final code after youe suggestion                               `boolean initialized=false;
 public void update(List<RTAData> data){
  dataProvider.getList().clear();
  
  if (!initialized) {
   dataProvider.addDataDisplay(cellTable);
   initialized=true;
  }
  dataProvider.setList(data); 
  }`

Answer (score 0):

The statement `dataProvider.addDataDisplay(cellTable)` adds a data display to this adapter. The current range of interest of the display will be populated with data.

If data display is already added and you try to add this again, it will throw this error.

To avoid this error, you can check condition and remove added display before add same data display. i.e:

```
if (getProvider().getDataDisplays().contains(cellTable)) {
            getProvider().removeDataDisplay(cellTable);
   }
getProvider().addDataDisplay(cellTable);
```

Comment: @SSR yeah it is wrong approach :(  here it can also initialize once and used and avoid this error. but I would like to know can you please tell me when such case required where needs to remove data display? because provider has `removeDataDisplay` so it may have some intention!!

Comment: If you have 2 views attached to same data and one view needs to be removed in a page/screen it makes sense to remove it.